# What would have happened had Davy Jones' Heart been lost with the Black Pearl?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

In *Pirates of the Caribbean - Dead Man's Chest* Jones attacked the Black Pearl thinking that his heart was still in the chest, as evident when after it was sunk he went to check it.

In the chance that Norrington hadn't stolen the heart and Jack's taunt was founded (as opposed to him just waving around a jar of dirt) what would have happened to the Heart when The Kraken destroyed the Black Pearl? Would Jones have died as a result?

Comment: The Monkees would have broken up, and Marsha Brady would have been devastated.

Answer (score 1):

It would've either gone with the Pearl and Jack into the "locker", or it would've dropped into the depths of the ocean. Either way, it would be easy for Jones to retrieve at either point.

Once he has the heart, he would control his own destiny, or at least his death, and could do whatever he pleased. Chances are he would continue to recruit and terrorize the seas as he saw fit. Given his history with Calypso and her binding he might try to find her. What he'd do with her is anyone's guess, but unpleasantness would be likely.

Comment: uhm I think he exactly KNEW about calypsos binding. If I'm not mistaken he even played a role in that one (giving the pirates the appropriate infos)....as for the reason....without his heart he feels NOTHING for her aside for possibly seeing her as a possible threat to his life.

Comment: @Thomas - er, right, need to stop writing when my brain is foggy

Comment: Welcome in the club there I think I said that in 2 answers and 4 comments of mine so far :D